# Page title before site name on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP site and am trying to figure out how to place the name of the page before the site name. Essentially, I'd like to change "ABC Inc. | About Us" to "About Us | ABC Inc.". Surprisingly, I ended up empty-handed after googling. Is this addressed by some plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your themes header.php file by replacing your  tag with the following:

```
<title><?php wp_title('|'); bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

Answer (score 1):

It is common to see usage of

```
<title><?php wp_title('|'); bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

or similar uses on the `<title>` tags; but according to the WordPRess Codex, [it should not be used](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title):

> The wp_title() function should not be used by a theme in conjunction
>   with other strings or functions (like concatenating with
>   bloginfo('name')) to write the content of the  element, because
>   it will render plugins unable to rewrite the whole title in case the
>   plugins use the wp_title filter do the rewrite, which is the best
>   practice. The use of this function is now a requirement for theme
>   developers.

The best way is to include a filter in your `functions.php` file:

```
function filter_wp_title( $title ) {

    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
    $filtered_title = $title . get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    $filtered_title .= ( ! empty( $site_description ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) ? ' | ' . $site_description: '';
    return $filtered_title;
}
```

For more info on filtering the title, [see the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a plugin, check out [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). Highly recommend it. You can drill down to writing custom titles for posts, categories, tags, homepage, etc.

Note: if it appears not to be working with your theme, click on "force rewrite titles".